# What does “bathe someone in a glow” mean?

Tags: phrases

I found the phrase “*bathe someone in a glow*” in the following sentence of the New York Times columnist, Maureen Dowd’s article titled “Memoirs of a Geisha.” (September 13).

I was attracted to the caption, and I thought it was a review of a memoire of the famous former Geisha residing in New York (I don’t know why Dowd likened Jacqueline a Geisha), but it was about the tape of an interview of Jackie Kennedy with Arthur Schlesinger, which was discovered 47 years after the interview took place.

> “In the 1964 tapes, the 34-year-old widow can be unsparing and caustic, except about her sometimes imperfect husband, whom *she bathes in an impossibly perfect glow*.”

As I’m not clear about the meaning of “bathe someone in glow,” I checked Google, and found no definition, but for an example of the usage in A Wagnerová - Czech Sociological Review, 1996.

> “It also affected the poor and property-less since they were no longer *bathed in the glow* from men at the peak of the social hierarchy.”

What does “*bathe imperfect husband in glow*” mean? Does it something to do with “put someone in the limelight”?

Answer (score 5):

*Bathe in a glow* simply means to have a favorable light cast on the person.  Typically it's worded the other way:  "He bathed in her glow" so the passage quoted is an unusual one.  However, I believe the intent is that she cast him in a perfect light, i.e. put him up on a pedestal.

Answer (score 4):

"Bathe in the glow of someone" generally means to share undeservedly in someone elses glory or fame, eg 'as a musician Yoko Ono bathed in the glow of John Lennon'.

"whom she bathes in an impossibly perfect glow" - not exactly sure about that usage. From context I would say the author meant "paints in a  perfect light" - ie. ignores all their faults and only mentions or remembers the good points.